# ADACON : Ada and connections SPOJ(TLE)

Tags: java, algorithm, math, number-theory

[This](http://www.spoj.com/problems/ADACON/) is a problem from SPOJ. I am getting TLE. Need help to improve its time complexity. There is one test-case that i know will fail. But I will take care of it after the time complexity is reduced.

> Ada the Ladybug was on a trip with her friends. They each bought a souvenir there. As all of them are mathematicians, everybody bought a number. They want to modify the numbers to have some connection between each other. They have decided to modify the numbers sou they would have their GCD greater than 1 ( **gcd(a<sub>1</sub>,a<sub>2</sub>,a<sub>3</sub>,...,a<sub>N</sub>) > 1)**. Anyway it is not easy to change a number - the only thing they can do is to go to a proffesor in mathematics, which could forge a number A into number **A+1** or **A-1**. As this operation is not cheap, they want to minimize number of such operations. A number might be forged any number of times.

**NOTE: gcd(a,0)==a (so gcd of two 0 is also 0)**

**Input**
The first line contains an integer `1 ≤ N ≤ 3*10^5`, the number of friend who were on trip (and also the number of numbers).

The second line contains N integers `0 ≤ a_i ≤ 10^6`

**Output**
Print a single line with minimum number of operations to make a connection between all numbers.

**Example Input**
5
3 9 7 6 31
**Example Output**
2
**Example Input 2**
9
3 4 5 7 8 9 11 12 13
**Example Output 2**
6
**Example Input 3**
5
7 7 11 17 1
**Example Output 3**
5

**APPROACH**

> First i find the primes upto `(largest/2 + 1)` element in the given array of numbers`(using function findPrimes())`. And then for every element in the array, find how many `operations` are going to be needed for each of the primes to be its divisor. The smallest summation for each prime, I am printing as solution.

**CODE**

```
import java.io.*;


public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int[] arr = new int[n];
        String[] strArr = br.readLine().split(" ");
        for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArr[i]);
            if(arr[i] > largest)
            {
                largest = arr[i];
            }
        }
        func(n,arr,largest);

    }

    public static void func(int n,int[] arr,int largest)
    {
        int[] primes = findPrimes(largest / 2 + 1);
        //int[] primes = findPrimes((int)Math.sqrt(largest));
        int lenOfPrimes = primes.length;
        int[] mat = new int[lenOfPrimes];
        for(int j = 0 ; j < lenOfPrimes ; j++)
        {
                if(arr[0] < primes[j])
                {
                    mat[j] = primes[j] - arr[0];
                }
                else if(arr[0] % primes[j] == 0)
                {
                    mat[j] = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    int rem = arr[0] % primes[j];
                    mat[j] = Math.min(rem,primes[j] - rem);
                }

        }
        for(int i = 1 ; i < n ; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0 ; j < lenOfPrimes ; j++)
            {
                if(arr[i] < primes[j])
                {
                    mat[j] = mat[j] + primes[j] - arr[i];
                }
                else if(arr[i] % primes[j] == 0)
                {
                    mat[j] = mat[j] + 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    int rem = arr[i] % primes[j];
                    mat[j] += Math.min(rem,primes[j] - rem);
                }
            }
        }

        int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < lenOfPrimes ;i++)
        {
            if(mat[i] < smallest)
                smallest = mat[i];
        }

        System.out.println(smallest);
    }

    public static int[] findPrimes(int upto)
    {
        boolean[] primes = new boolean[upto + 1];
        for(int i = 0 ; i < upto + 1 ; i++)
            primes[i] = true;

        int count = 0;
        primes[0] = primes[1] = false;

        int limit = (int)Math.sqrt(upto + 1);
        for(int i = 2 ; i < upto + 1; i++)
        {
            if(primes[i] == true)
            {
                count++;
                if(i <= limit)
                {
                    for(int j = i * i ; j < upto + 1 ; j += 2 * i)
                    {
                        primes[j] = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        int[] primeContainer = new int[count];
        int index = 0;
        for(int i = 2 ; i < upto + 1 ; i++)
        {
            if(primes[i] == true)
            {
                primeContainer[index++] = i;
                if(index == count)
                    break;
            }
        }
        return primeContainer;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should explain the logic and thinking behind your code.

Comment: Here is a hint: take a look at the a_i mod 2. Now, how many operations would it take to make them all be divisible by 2? Now look at the a_i mod 3,...

Comment: I have added my approach. Are you trying to convey the same or something different?

Comment: More for [**Code Review**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Your approach looks like my hint. I see no reason use `largest/2` as the prime limit,  I would use `(smallest + N)/2` since we know it takes N operations as a worst case to make everything divisible by 2.

Comment: @JoopEggen Definitely not: "There is one test-case that i know will fail." sounds like the code does not work as intended, so it's not fit for Code Review.

Comment: @Mast. I know few test cases(involving 0's in the input) that will fail. but before rectifying that, i want to get rid of this TLE.

Comment: @JamesKPolk. by "N", you mean number of elements?

Comment: I don't mind your approach, although I'm not sure Stack Overflow agrees with it. All I'm saying is it won't fit Code Review until it's fixed, something Joop suggested.

Comment: @Mast thanks I'll remember

Comment: @JamesKPolk. I think we can't take (smallest + n) / 2. Your approach would fail for 7,14.

Comment: Well you may be right, I'll think it over but it sounds like you're ahead of me.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that you are trying will give you correct answer. But since there are many prime numbers till 1000000, (~ 78000) hence 78000*300000 will definately give you TLE.
Try to think in terms of sieve. The sieve of eratosthenes works in O(nlogn) time.

Now you would have already figured out that you would change numbers such that it is divisible by some prime number. (As in your algorithm you are considering only prime numbers). So now lets take a prime number say 7. Now you need to find number of transformation of numbers from 0 to 3, because you need to change these numbers to 0. Similarly you need to find number of numbers from 4 to 10 as you will change them to 7 to get them divisible by 7 considering minimum operations. Similarly you would do the same to numbers from 11 to 17, changing them to 14, and so on for rest of the numbers till 1000000. You need to do the same for all prime numbers. This can be achieved using sieve.

The number of operations in this case will be n/2 + n/3 + n/5 + n/7 + n/11 + .... ~ nlogn.

You can read more about sieve from here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sieve-of-eratosthenes/

Comment: How this approach is supposed to solve the problem? Would you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

May be its too late but let me answer this.
I was able to sole this problem using below approach.
My Java Solution take 3.8 S on SPOJ for all 15 test cases combine.
1.Find prime divisors of n in O(log n)
Source https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/prime-factorization-using-sieve-olog-n-multiple-queries/
2. While computing factorization store prime divisors in array  let say UniquePrimeWhicheDividsAtleastOneNumber[]
here is a catch always keep 2 in this UniquePrimeWhicheDividsAtleastOneNumber if its not available.
UniquePrimeWhicheDividsAtleastOneNumber[0]=2
3. now you can loop through these primes and find the sum of smallest reminders by these primes.

```
        long minTemp = 0, minAns = Long.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < UniquePrimeWhicheDividsAtleastOneNumber.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                int rem = InputNumbers[j] % UniquePrimeWhicheDividsAtleastOneNumber[i];
                minTemp += Math.min(rem, UniquePrimeWhicheDividsAtleastOneNumber[i] - rem);
                if (minTemp > minAns)
                    break;// no need to compute sum of reminders if it exceeded the current minimum.
            }
            minAns = Math.min(minAns, minTemp);
            minTemp = 0;
        }
        
        minAns --> is your answer.
```